# Excel formulas and auto fill

Tags: excel, vba

I am building an excel sheet for our sales team that calculates pricing for a hosted system based on the users.  It also contains the Part #s for our quoting software so it makes the whole process much easier.

What I have currently have setup forces the user to enter data into the quantity field.  I have a spreadsheet that has specs for the servers based on user count.  I am just a n00b with excel so I am not sure how to set it up so that I can enter a number in a single field and then based on that number the hardware for the server, RMM monitoring, and exchange mailboxes, etc populates.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [tables](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c). It automatically copies all your formulas when you enter a new record.

Comment: That isn't exactly what I was thinking but I think it might suit me for what I am trying to do.  I will try to get it working for me and get back to you.

Comment: Okay, so I have been doing some more research on this and I have used SUMIF for certain values and it works just fine.  So I am trying to use similar logic for other fields and it has become rather complex.  I have a table on a different sheet and I am trying to use ranges in IF statements to put information into those fields but I am at a loss for how to get ranges to work in an IF statement.  Any ideas?  Am I making sense?

Comment: You can't use ranges in IF statements. (Well, you can, but you really don't want to use Array formulas unless absolutely necessary.) In your case, I think it will be the VLOOKUP that helps. Try playing with that to retrieve data from the other sheet. Keep in mind that you might need the Range Lookup to be TRUE. [More info](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions02.html)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but here are some of the most useful functions that work with ranges: SUMIF, COUNTIF, SUMIFS, COUNTIFS, VLOOKUP, MATCH+INDEX.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by using sumif and nested if statements.  Thanks for the help all.